# in json schemas can you annotate default value as this.parent.key?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I have a schema with a $def:{.., "machine":{.. ,"displayName":{..}} } which will validate a structure like "machines":{"FA23":{..},"FA41":[..}}.
I'd like to annotate that the default for the displayName property will be the machine's key ("FA23" for example). Is that at all possible without procedurally generating the schema?

the reason behind this is i want to avoid having a separate structure holding the default values: instead i'll parse the schema after a successful validation and fill-in the missing values with the specified defaults.
I'd like the parsing function to be as general as possible, to allow repeated usage over different projects. Therefore the defaults must hold the exact value or a safe way to get it without schema-specific logic.

I'm using draft-07, but i'm not yet committed to a specific draft.
I'm also working in javascript under node.js@v14-latest enviroment (node-red) but i'd like to avoid the use of modules or code to generate the schema if possible.

I'm using a list of object properties instead than an array because that's the structure i actually work with at runtime, allowing me to write it directly to a file without a conversion step.

A subset of my schema so far looks like

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title":"commonConfigSchema",
    "description":"global common config for this project",
    "$defs":{
        "javascriptFalsy":{
            "enum":[false, 0, null, ""]
        },
        "macKey":{
            "type":"string",
            "enum":["FA419","FA420","FA421","FA422","FA423","MO41","MO42","OMET"]
        },
        "signalKey":{
            "type":"string",
            "enum":["noop","A1","A2","A3","A4","B","C1","C2","D","E"],
            "default":"noop"
        },
        "towerDevice":{
            "type":"string",
            "enum":["redLight","greenLight","horn"]
        },
        "machine":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "displayName":{"type":"string", "default":"this.parent.key"},
                "cellHeaderText":{"type":"string", "default":"Linea + this.displayName"},
                "toA3Timeout":{"type":"integer", "minimum":0, "default":20000},
                "toA4Timeout":{"type":"integer", "minimum":0, "default":"120*60*1000"},
                "initCellSignalKey":{"$ref":"#/$defs/signalKey", "default":"noop"},
                "initTowerBits":{
                    "type":"object",
                    "propertyNames":{"$ref":"#/$defs/towerDevice"},
                    "patternProperties":{".":{"enum":[0, 1, true, false], "default":0}}
                }
            },
            "$comment":"exactly all the props are required",
            "additionalProperties":false,
            "required":["displayName", "cellHeaderText", "toA3Timeout", "toA4Timeout", "initCellSignalKey", "initTowerBits"]
        }
    },
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "machines":{
            "$description": "holding machine-specific configs. Made up of macKey:config pairs",
            "type":"object",
            "propertyNames":{"$ref":"#/$defs/macKey"},
            "patternProperties":{".":{"$ref":"#/$defs/machine"} },
            //"required":{"$ref":"#/$defs/macKey/enum"},
            "required":["FA419","FA420","FA421","FA422","FA423","MO41","MO42","OMET"]
            "additionalProperties":false,
        }
    },
    "required":["cellsLayout", "machines"],
    "additionalProperties":false,
}

p.s. as you can see from the commented out "required" i was also struggling with binding that string array to my enum definition, thus avoiding redundancies. But $refs are schemas, not string arrays :/
I found this old answer [link][1] stating that it's not possible, has anything changed?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set `default` by directly referencing a value in the instance. However, since all possible values are known, there is a way to do it with the `if`/`then` keywords. It's not a great solution, but it is a solution.

```json
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "macKey": { "const": "FA419" }
        },
        "required": ["macKey"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "machine": {
            "properties": {
              "displayName": { "default": "FA419" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

This says, if `/macKey` is "FA419", then the default of `/machine/displayName` is "FA419". If you add one of these conditional schemas to the `allOf` for each possible `/macKey`, you'll get the behavior you're looking for.